# C++ Помогите с заданием, с массивами

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы

Не могу понять, как написать этот бесконечный цикл.

[image: Задание]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа этого:

```
double term = 1, sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
{
    term *= a[i];
    sum  += sqrt(term);
}
```

Comment: вроде  `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` так правильнее ?

Comment: @DmitriyVizir В вопросе индексы от 1 до *n* - я следовал вопросу. Писать `a[i+1]` мне представляется менее удобным, чем указать цикл от 1 до *n*.

Comment: тогда прошу прощения )